# ConstraintLayout does not render correctly outside blueprint mode

Tags: android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I started using Android Studio 2.2 and ConstraintLayout today, but I'm having some issues with the rendering. When using Blueprint Mode everything appears fine. When using Design Mode, the objects are stuck at the top left corner all mashed together.

Android Studio warning: onMeasure error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidget.immediateConnect(Landroid/support/constraint/solver/widgets/ConstraintAnchor$Type;Landroid/support/constraint/solver/widgets/ConstraintWidget;Landroid/support/constraint/solver/widgets/ConstraintAnchor$Type;II)V
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.setChildrenConstraints(ConstraintLayout.java:517)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.updateHierarchy(ConstraintLayout.java:433)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure_Original(ConstraintLayout.java:728)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:545)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:342)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$72(RenderTask.java:659)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
```

Is this an unsolvable error in Android Studio or is there something that is solvable? SDK is updated.

**EDIT**

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/about"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView34"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView33" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: add your xml file

Comment: XML file added.

Comment: layout is ok 2 solutions change the about drawable to @mipmap/ic_launcher and try again
second from file menu choose invalidate caches / restart

Comment: Do you mean mipmap or drawable? I don't have a mipmap IC launcher

Comment: any other picture that is small like app icon

Comment: Tried with ic_launcher from drawable: No effect. One option left, trying them now

Comment: ok from file menu try invalidate / restart

Comment: That worked. It shows up as supposed to in Design Mode.

Comment: i added my comment as answer choose it as correct answer

Answer (score 51, accepted):

as mentioned here
[Constraint Layout Alpha8 release notes](http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayoutalpha8isnowavailable)

Note: due to API change, you might have to restart Android Studio 2.2 after upgrading to alpha 8 for layout preview to work.

so From the menu bar, select `file` and choose `invalidate caches / restart`

Comment: am using `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2` and restarting is not working. still am getting this error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.setOptimizationLevel(I)V`

Comment: may be no method with this name in new version or you have to update constraint from sdk updater

Comment: may you have to post it as an issue in stackoverflow after trying it in a new project

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem after update

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
```

downgrade back to 1.1.3 resolve problem