# using constraint layout . every things seems to perfect in the blue print, but when i run the application the views are not in place

Tags: android, xml, layout, constraints

i am building a single screen as for my project but facing some issues 
i am using the code provided below
i am facing the issues that every thing seems to good in buleprint/design tab but every things messed up  views does not remain on the place the are supposed to be!

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.abhisharma.themobileshop.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="393dp"
    android:layout_height="241dp"

    android:scaleType="center"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/a"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-9dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="129dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Top Brands"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Top Deals!!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="377dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:text="Open seven days a week 9 am to 7 pm (except public holidays"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact : +919999049952"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="478dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="shop number 6, the main market faridabad ,121007"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="We deal all kind of mobile phone,aaccessories and repair"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.565"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BEST PRICE IN THE MARKET"
    android:layout_marginRight="86dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/apple"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="109dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/gio"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="259dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/sam"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="207dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="113dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/leno"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="289dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered
[ConstraintLayout does not render correctly outside blueprint mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678608/constraintlayout-does-not-render-correctly-outside-blueprint-mode)

as mentioned here http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayoutalpha8isnowavailable

Note: due to API change, you might have to restart Android Studio 2.2 after upgrading to alpha 8 for layout preview to work.

so From the menu bar, select file and choose invalidate caches / restart

Comment: it didnt helped :/

Comment: i have problem when i run , application 
it seems good in desin mode